# Running benchmarks of subfolders from the project root

Tags: go, benchmarking

I have a project with a binary which entrypoint is located in `./cmd/<my-project>/main.go`.
I've added a benchmark in `./cmd/<my-project>/main_test.go`.

Now I want to execute this benchmark from the repository root.
I've tried to execute something like `go test -bench=./cmd/<my-project>/main` in various alternations (like for example `go test -bench=./cmd/<my-project>/main_test.go` or `go test -bench=./cmd/<my-project>`) but I couldn't get it to work.

The error I always get is:

`can't load package: package github.com/<username>/<my-project>: no Go files in /home/<user>/go/src/github.com/<username>/<my-project>`

and it's true, I have no `*.go` files in my project root.

All I came up with is changing into the directory first and run the benchmark with `go test -bench=.

However, as my program depends on the current working directory and the result is heavily depending on that it would be great to be able to execute it in another directory than the `cmd/<my-project>` one. (If this is good or not isn't part of the question :))

**Update after the first comment:**

I get it to run with `go test -bench=. /cmd/<my-project>` but the benchmark get's executed as if it would be run in the `./cmd/<my-project>` directory.
I've noticed similiar behaviour in 'normal tests' - but that wasn't a problem for me at any time.

So, my program does scan the current directory for files directories depending on the current working directory, this results in only two files found (`main.go` and `main_test.go`) where the benchmark isn't really helpful.

Comment: It is executable but it executes the benchmark as if I'm in that directory. So my program scans for files/directories in the current working directory and it only finds the two files (`main.go` and `main_test.go`) in `./cmd/<my-project>/` and not all files inside the project root.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So to run the benchmarks:

```
go test -bench=. ./cmd/<my-project>
```

However, you are wanting to control the working directory, so really you want to run it from somewhere else. What you are looking for is the `-c` flag. It will create a binary instead of running the tests. You can then run the binary (and therefore your tests and benchmarks) where you want.

```
go test -c ./cmd/my_proj
my_proj.test -test.bench=.
```

**NOTE**: Flags are prefixed with `test.` when you compile the tests.

Comment: Thank you, it is working but it is running only one time, not `n` times. So, it is like running the binary after compiling.

My func looks like this: 
`for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ { main() }` (not a single line in actual code of course)

Comment: Can you post more code? Sounds like something is setup funny

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, I did something wrong. It is working like you said.

Comment: Ah, glad to hear it.